# eigenvalue test for linear time-varying systems

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, stability-theory

Consider the linear time-varying system given by

$\dot x(t)=A(t)x(t)$

Denote by $\lambda_\max(t)$ the maximum eigenvalue of $A(t)+A^T(t)$. Suppose that there exist constants $\alpha\gt0$ and $\gamma$ such that $\lambda_\max(t)$ satisfies

$\int_\tau^t\lambda_\max(s)ds\le-\alpha(t-\tau)+\gamma$ where $\forall t\ge\tau$

Prove that $x_e=0$ is uniformly exponentially stable.

I was given a hint: Examine $d\over dt$$\Vert x\Vert_2^2$

But still, have no clue how to solve this problem. Also why we consider maximum eigenvalue for $A(t)+A^T(t)$? Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

Following the hint we examine the derivative of the square of the Euclidean norm. I use $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ to denote the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$. We then have for all $t$
$$\frac{d}{dt}\|x(t)\|^2 = \frac{d}{dt} \langle x(t), x(t) \rangle
= \langle A(t)x(t), x(t) \rangle + \langle x(t), A(t)x(t) \rangle$$
$$=\langle (A(t)+A(t)^T)x(t), x(t) \rangle \leq \lambda_{max}(t)\|x(t)\|^2 $$
Integrating from $\tau$ to $t$ we get
$$ \|x(t)\|^2 \leq \|x(\tau)\|^2 + \int_{\tau}^t \lambda_{max}(s)\|x(s)\|^2 ds$$
Gronwall's lemma yields
$$ \|x(t)\|^2 \leq \exp\left( \int_{\tau}^t \lambda_{max}(s) ds\right)
\|x(\tau)\|^2 $$
With the given assumption we obtain
$$ \|x(t)\|^2 \leq e^\gamma e^{-a(t-\tau)}
\|x(\tau)\|^2 $$
As $a>0$ and $\gamma$ are independent of $t,\tau$ this shows uniform exponential stability.